# Get generic class type and name in abstract class without constructor

Tags: java

My class:

```
public class MyClass extends AbstracyEntity {
   
   ...

}
```

My service:

```
@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class MyService extends MyAbstractService<MyClass> {
   
   ...

}
```

My abstract class:

```
public abstract class MyAbstractService<E extends AbstracyEntity> {
   
   public void myAbstractMethod() {
      Class<?> c = E.getClass();
      System.out.println(c.getSimpleName());
   }

}
```

Finally expected output from Abstract Service -> myAbstractMethod() :

```
MyClass
```

From whatever entity my abstracted service is abstracted from, I need the related entity's type and class name. Because I aim to create dynamic queries with common conditions with entity name. Example:

```
String sql = "Select t From " + E.getClass.getSimpleName() + " t where ...";
```

I solved the problem by defining a constructor in an abstract class, but I don't think it's the best solution. What is the best solution?

Comment: Why do you need a constructor of abstract class?

Comment: I dont need. I just try

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may infer generic type parameter via something like:

```java
ResolvableType type = 
 ResolvableType.forClass(getClass()).as(MyAbstractService.class);
Class<?>[] typeArguments = type.resolveGenerics(Object.class);
return (Class<E>) typeArguments[0];
```

However nothing prevents you from writing that in more clear way:

```java
public abstract class MyAbstractService<E extends AbstracyEntity> {

   private Class<E> type;

   pubic MyAbstractService(Class<E> type) {
       this.type = type;
   }

}

public class MyService extends MyAbstractService<MyClass> {

    pubic MyService() {
        super(MyClass.class);
    }
}
```

Comment: In which class will I use the first code you wrote?

Comment: that would make sense to define `Class<E> getType()` method in `MyAbstractService` class.